# How would I access a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am currently working with the ROBLOX API service and giving me the audit log from a group. The only problem which has occurred now is: I don't know how I would use it normally. Anyone of you got maybe an idea how I would access the date: dictionary -> data . The dictionary is looking like this when I use: `for x in finalresponse:`

[image] .

When I then just print the dictionary by itself it comes this:

[image]

So, as I already asked: How would I access then in the dictionary the list data with all the other important data?

Comment: `for item in finalresponse['data']:`…?!

Comment: Oh, lol. Imma see if this is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print(finalresponse["data"])
```

Basic :)

Comment: Yep that's working. I have never been that good with lists sooo yep. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it even if it's not mandatory.